# Do I need to have express.static if I use res.send File

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, production-environment, mern

I have a MERN app that I am trying to deploy. I noticed that during production its important to have the following lines in the index.js file for the backend:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

So my question is: since res.sendFile is getting the index.html file, why do I need to use express.static? In other words, how would the code be different? Is it because there are two servers for the frontend and the backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [Express Guide Static Files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have a general idea of what express.static does. It's just that in the context of my question, what purpose does it serve?